# Redirect anonymous users to login when trying to view profile

Tags: profile

On our Drupal 7.38 and CiviCRM 4.6.8 site, the "profile listings and forms" permission is set to authenticated users and above.

Accordingly, anonymous users receive the standard warning when trying to view a profile:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
The requested Profile (gid=20) is disabled OR … etc.
```

How do we redirect anonymous users to a login screen rather than receive this warning?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the login_toboggan drupal module? Not sure if it works with Civi profiles but it might. It provides the option to add a login form on all "access denied" screens.